# Single String object unmarshal gives UnmarshalException

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshall just a simple xml String.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><error>No images were found for the pro(s) entered.</error>
```

Here is my code.

```
             try{
                    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(String.class);
                    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                    StringReader reader = new StringReader(output);
                    String error = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader).toString();

                    RateQuoteError rateQuoteError = new RateQuoteError(error);
                    List<RateQuoteError> errorsList = new ArrayList<RateQuoteError>();
                    errorsList.add(rateQuoteError);
                    getPODResponse.setRateQuoteErrors(errorsList);
                }
                catch(UnmarshalException ume2)
                { 
                    ume2.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

May be this is the easiest unmarshalling exercise but im getting following error.

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"error"). Expected elements are (none)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:662)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:120)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1063)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:480)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:150)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:378)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
try{
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(String.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    StreamSource reader = new StreamSource(new StringReader(output));
    JAXBElement<String> error = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader, String.class);

    RateQuoteError rateQuoteError = new RateQuoteError(error.getValue);
    List<RateQuoteError> errorsList = new ArrayList<RateQuoteError>();
    errorsList.add(rateQuoteError);
    getPODResponse.setRateQuoteErrors(errorsList);
} catch(UnmarshalException ume2) {
    ume2.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

More examples: [How to parse a String containing XML in Java and retrieve the value of the root node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408504/how-to-parse-a-string-containing-xml-in-java-and-retrieve-the-value-of-the-root)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use the unmarshalled string on your `RateQuoteError` object. How does your `RateQuoteError` look? you can actually use JAXB to unmarshal it directly to your Object, with the right annotaions to your `RateQuoteError` object:

```
RateQuoteError rateQuoteError = (RateQuoteError) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

For annotations, take a look at this: [convert xml to java object using jaxb (unmarshal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221136/convert-xml-to-java-object-using-jaxb-unmarshal)