# Reading XML tag in java

Tags: java, xml, string, parsing

I have a JAVA string that is holding an XML document. What is the easiest way to parse the string and extract the value, in this case "abc" from the following:

```
<...>
    <book>abc</book>
</...>
```

Thanks

Comment: In my personal opinion, XPath is powerful tools to extract information from XML : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java , for this particular XML the XPath expression would be as simple as : `//book`

Answer (score 1):

Try code of these links :

> [How to parse a String containing XML in Java and retrieve the value of the root node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408504/how-to-parse-a-string-containing-xml-in-java-and-retrieve-the-value-of-the-root)
>
> http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/ParseanXMLstringUsingDOMandaStringReader.htm

Comment: String xml = "<message>HELLO!</message>";
org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
try {
    org.jdom.Document doc = saxBuilder.build(new StringReader(xml));
    String message = doc.getRootElement().getText();
    System.out.println(message);
} catch (JDOMException e) {
    // handle JDOMException
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle IOException
}

If I use this code, I get an error saying  pacakage org.jdom.input does not exist. Where can I get it from? I'm new to java.

Comment: @Alex You need to add the JDOM2 dependency to your project. To find out how to do that, just google `<your ide> add library` and use the JDOM2 jar you get from [here](http://www.jdom.org/downloads/index.html) (click "JDOM 2.0.6")

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can I get value of a child element using JDOM?