# How can I parse a String into an XML Document in Java?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a string that contains an XML, into a Document Object in Java. Here's the source code of the method:

```
private Document getDocument(String xml) {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;  

    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    return doc;
}
```

What I always get as a value of the doc variable according to the debugger is

> [#document: null]

Does anyone have a clue what is wrong?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a String containing XML in Java and retrieve the value of the root node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408504/how-to-parse-a-string-containing-xml-in-java-and-retrieve-the-value-of-the-root)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal as the debugger is invoking `Document#toString()` which prints `[node_name: node_value]`. The node value of a document node is null according to the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html). If you want to print the name of the root element, you should evaluate `doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName()`.

Comment: Is that really worth an answer? It looks a good comment, but really, an answer?!

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you post the XML document as well to see the structure, but this is what I do to read an XML.

```
    // Opening and creating file Objects
    File inputFile = new File(xmlFile);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

After that, you can use the `doc.getElementsByTagName("Root Node");` to get the root node of your XML. The object has a lot of properties, like `getFirstChild()` or `getChildNodes()`  depending on the strucure, Ill suggest to read this:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_intro.asp